# Google Sheets ImportXML Xpath?

Tags: xpath, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am attempting to scrape a website for a value for a rank check sheet, I unfortunately dont have much experience with web scraping or anything of the sort and was wondering how I'd go about finding the xPath query for the Global Rank number.

ex. https://osu.ppy.sh/users/13992437 scraping this for the correct value would return 185,917 on the sheet.

Currently I've tried copying the xPath just from the inspect element but it returns a "Imported Content is Empty." due to my lack of experience I'm not really sure what to do going for this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected value? Can I ask you about the details of your expected values?

Comment: For example the expected value from this specific page 

https://osu.ppy.sh/users/13992437 

would return 185,917 on the sheet or whatever number is under the "Global Ranking" on the webpage.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve a value of `185,917` from the URL `https://osu.ppy.sh/users/13992437` using the built-in function of Google Spreadsheet.

In this case, how about the following sample formula?

#### Sample formula:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML("https://osu.ppy.sh/users/13992437","//meta[@name='description']/@content"),"Global #([0-9,]*)")
```

#### Testing:

When the above formula is used, the following result is obtained. In the current stage, the value of `185,994` is obtained.

[image]

Comment: @NorthRL Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand your question with your cooperation. Thank you, too.